# Вопрос закрыт - открыт - закрыт - перенесён - заблокирован - разблокирован - отклонён. Нормально ли это?

Tags: поддержка, перенос-вопросов

Задал сегодня [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10892/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-async-await-%D0%B2-java) и был заинтересован его [статусами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10892/revisions)

[image: Ревизии сообщения]

- вопрос закрыт
- открыт
- закрыт
- перенесён
- заблокирован
- разблокирован
- отклонён

проще говоря "генг бенг"  :)

и в [итоге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183831/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-async-await-%D0%B2-java)

Собственно вопрос: насколько это нормальная практика для SO или ru.SO?

Comment: e.g. `вопрос закрыт — открыт — закрыт — перенесён — заблокирован — разблокирован — отклонён`

Comment: Квертий вспоминает, как пользоваться инструментами модератора :D

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на вопрос. Почему это вообще задано на Мете? По формату это вопрос скорее в чат)

Comment: Между прочим, подобный вопрос прекрасно зашёл на enSO 7 лет назад: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16539245/2110496)

Comment: Вопрос не подобный он другой. Мой будет ли async await в Java

Comment: Добавил ссылку на вопрос

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, ну отклонён-то не мной)

Comment: Не хватает пункта: пользователь забанен.

Comment: Побочный эффект переноса мета-вопроса туда-сюда

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В целом - нормально. Не берусь судить действия модератора. Может быть для переноса вопроса требуется, чтобы он был открыт. При этом сам перенос подразумевает закрытие и блокировку, что [можно видеть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10892/timeline) по одинаковым временным меткам для событий (выделил синим цветом):

> [image: История сообщения]

По последним шагам тоже есть определённая логика системы. В частности, если вопрос был перенесён с одного сайта на другой, и на последнем его тоже закрыли, то сообщение разблокируется (но остаётся закрытым) и миграция отклоняется. Оба действия выполнены атомарно (выделено зелёным).

При этом, что на одном сайте, что на другом вопросы живут своей отдельной жизнью, хоть и остаются связанными. По сути это как две копии одного и того же.